# Google Chrome extension $.ajax post event handler error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I made an login function which returns:

```
return $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: CHEAPWATCHER.config.domain + 'api/Authenticate',
    data: data
 });
```

fiddler show that request was successful and I got my token, but chrome throws this kind of exception:

> extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8 Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined

I tried to debug and found out that my login function's return statement is making this error. Can someone explain why this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at the [documentation for `$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> Returns: [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)
>   ...
>   The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise (see Deferred object for more information).

It's important to understand it does not return the data. It cannot, in any case: this is an *asynchronous* request, so it will actually happen some time after you call `ajax()`, but the returned value has to be provided immediately.

You absolutely should look at [this canonical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) on the topic of using data collected by `ajax()`. It shows how to use `success` parameter, and explains why asynchronous requests can't be used in a "traditional" `return` way.

Alternatively, you can do it in the Promise way. The returned object has a function `.done(callback)` that will call this callback - later, when the request succeeds - with the data.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: CHEAPWATCHER.config.domain + 'api/Authenticate',
  data: data
}).done(function(result) {
  // Do something (but not return!) with the result
});
```

Again, to hammer it home: there is *no possible way* to return this value, since it won't actually happen when you submit the request but later, and you can't "wait" for it.

Comment: Thanks mate! You saved me lots of time :))

Comment: I just saw that $http.post method also returns jqXHR object, and when I return it everything works. How is that?